# Is there a way to create and access a method within a standard javascript function?

Tags: javascript

It's possible to create a method like this in a literal object :

https://jsfiddle.net/7q1530sp/2

```
let o = {
    f: function f () {
        alert("f")
    }
}
o.f();
```

Since function is also an object, I'd like to be able to do the same within a function I tried this but it doesn't work, is there a way ?

https://jsfiddle.net/7q1530sp/1

```
function o(){
    f: function f () {
        alert("f")
    }
}

o.f();
```

Comment: What do you expect `o()` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define as many functions-within-functions as you like!

```js
let f1 = function() {
  let f2 = function() {
    let f3 = function() {
      return 'functions';
    };
    return 'love ' + f3();
  };
  return 'I ' + f2();
};

console.log(f1());
```

If you want to define functions as properties, you could also do the following:

```js
let f1 = function() {
  return 'I ';
};
f1.f2 = function() {
  return 'love ';
};
f1.f3 = function() {
  return 'functions';
};

console.log(f1() + f1.f2() + f1.f3());
```

Note that this property assignment works exactly the same way that objects work; e.g.

```
let f1 = function(){}; f1.someProperty = 'someValue';
```

vs

```
let o = {}; o.someProperty = 'someValue';
```

The assignment of properties to a function doesn't need to occur within the function body, but functions certainly could assign properties to themselves:

```
let f = function() {
  f.a = 'b';
  f.c = 'd';
};
```

Note that in this case the `f.a` and `f.c` properties wouldn't exist until you actually call the function by performing: `f()`.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Just one more question by curiosity : why can't I do create property function f2 WITHIN f ?

Comment: @user310291 a) because you used the wrong syntax (what you wrote is a [labelled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) local function declaration) and b) because you didn't call `f()` so the code within it isn't executed

Answer (score 1):

You have to define it outside of the function:

```js
function o(){
  console.log("o");
}

o.f = function(){
  console.log("f");
}

o.f()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create objects within a function in Javascript.
Here is your code:

```
function o() {
  const d = {
    f: function f() {
      alert("f")
     },
   }
   d.f();
  }
 o();
```

Output:
https://jsfiddle.net/pLjc0vbf/1/

Comment: Thanks for answer may be I need for later but for now what I wanted is rather o.f() ;)